# In python, return value only when the function is used in an assignment

Tags: python

I would like to do something like this:

```
def f():
    if assignment_requested: return "Return something"
    else: print "Return nothing"
```

which should give:

```
>>> f()
Return nothing
>>> a = f()
>>> print a
Return something
```

I cannot find any way to check for whether the function is called alone `f()` or is used to assign a variable `a=f()`. **Is there a way to do this ?**

For example, in Matlab, it is possible using `if nargout>0`.

Comment: Why would this matter? What do you think happens to the return value if it isn't used?

Comment: @user, one thing is that it prints on screen, which can be annoying. Second thing is that you might want the function to actually do something different depending on whether the return is used or not.

Comment: Python only prints the value to the screen at the interactive prompt, and if you want to suppress that, you can just do something like `_ = whatever()` instead of `whatever()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't and should not worry about this. Use different functions or have your function take an argument that controls what is returned, if this is an issue.

Assignments are wide and varied and can include assignments that are explicitly discarded again. For example, if your function was used in a comparison expression:

```
if f() == 'Return something':
```

there is no assignment, but the return value *matters*.

Using different functions:

```
def f_with_return():
    return 'something'

def f_without_return():
    f_with_return()  # ignores the return value!
    print "I won't return something"
```

or parameters:

```
def f(return_something=True):
    if return_something:
        return 'something'
    print "I won't return something"
```

lets you control what is returned.

However, if you don't explicitly return anything, Python *still returns a value*: `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically, this is not a feature of python, but I don't understand why it should not have it. I don't get the philosophy.

Comment: There is no advantage to controlling return values in Python, because object lifetime is controlled with reference counting, not with assignments to names. As such there are many more ways to use return values from functions beyond assignments, and having to explain how that'd all work would get ugly fast. Plus, all use-cases for `nargs` in Matlab can easily be handled differently in Python, so why add a feature that would complicate understanding of what happens?